# How to apply binning results to raw data?

Tags: r, intervals, binning

To categorize the continuous variables, I used binning with the following code

```
german<-read.csv("http://freakonometrics.free.fr/german_credit.csv", header=TRUE)
F=c(1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)
for(i in F) german[,i]=as.factor(german[,i])
str(german)

german_interval<-classIntervals(german$Duration.of.Credit..month., n=4 ,style = "equal" )
german_interval
```

The result of binning is as follows.

```
style: equal
  one of 4,960 possible partitions of this variable into 4 classes
 [4,21) [21,38) [38,55) [55,72] 
    554     359      73      14
```

So, I want to change the value 4<=x<21 =1, 21<=x<38 =2, 38<=x<55 =3, 55<=x<72=4.
Then, how to apply this value in raw data??

Also, If you see that raw data, there is target variable. It is a Creditability. And,I want to know the ratio of the target variable to each section. Specifically, [4, 21]=0:?% / 1:?%, [21,35]=0:?%, 1:?%. how to do that as R code?

Comment: Creditability is a factor variable with two levels: "0" and "1". You are asking for a ratio of something to something, but it is not at all clear what those two "somethings" are. I think you need to be more specific about the needed calculations of many more people will join me in asking htat this question be closed for lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the intervals you have with `cut`, by simply specifying the breaks.

```
## Some sample data
set.seed(2017)
x = rnorm(20,36,13)

cut(x, breaks=c(4,21,38,55,72), include.lowest=TRUE, right=FALSE)
```

> ```
>  [1] [38,55) [21,38) [38,55) [4,21)  [21,38) [38,55) [4,21)  [21,38) [21,38)
> [10] [55,72] [38,55) [55,72] [21,38) [38,55) [4,21)  [38,55) [21,38) [38,55)
> [19] [21,38) [21,38)
> Levels: [4,21) [21,38) [38,55) [55,72]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `classInt::classinterval`, a simpler solution would be to use `cut` in base:

```
german$gp <- cut(german$Duration.of.Credit..month., breaks=4, include.lowest=T)
levels(german$gp) <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: If you see that german's raw data, there is target variable. It is a Creditability. And,I want to know the ratio of the target variable to each section.Specifically, [4, 21]=0:40% / 1:60%, [21,35]=0:20%, 1:80%. how to that? Thank you for your nice code!

Comment: @이순우 How were we supposed to know that? Make your questions complete or break them up into separate questions. Use [edit] to amend questions. It's really annoying to have followup questions posted in comments. Also annoying not to see an upvote for useful code.

Answer (score 0):

When the intervals are closed on the left the base function findInterval is most succinct.

```
german_interval<-findInterval(german$Duration.of.Credit..month., c(4,21,38,55,72) )
german_interval
```

This function naturally provides a numeric value and I prefer the left-closed default.